# Apache reload fails if try to use CSP On and CSPFileTypes

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a dual Linux system where I'm trying to enable `CSPFileTypes *` which is required for REST API use.  Apache has been working fine prior to this.

```
Alias /testrest/ /app/vubis/TESTSERVICE/
<Directory "/app/vubis/TESTSERVICE/">
    CSP On
    CSPFileTypes *
    AllowOverride None
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    <FilesMatch "\.(log|ini|pid|exe)$">
    Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

But when I attempt to reload Apache I get:

```
Reloading httpd: not reloading due to configuration syntax error
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I can only get the reload to work if I comment out the `CSP On` and `CSPFileTypes *` line.

Is there some configuration setup somewhere that's preventing the use of `CSP` and `CSPFileTypes`?

Answer (score 0):

The `CSP` and `CSPFileTypes` directives are non-standard directives and are provided by third-party modules.
It seems you need two DSO modules `CSPa24.so` and `CSPa24Sys.so` in a location in your filesystem loaded by Apache.

Have a look at the first two lines of the example configuration `LoadModule csp_module_sa ...` and `CSPModulePath ...`.

From [Recommended Option: Apache API Module without NSD (CSPa24.so)](https://docs.intersystems.com/healthconnectlatest/csp/docbook/Doc.View.cls?KEY=GCGI_ux#GCGI_ux_api) (InterSystems Documentation):

> The modules **CSPa24.so** (Runtime) and **CSPa24Sys.so** (Web Gateway systems management) are dynamically linked modules (DSOs).
>
> Configure the web server to recognize CSP requests (files of type **.csp**, **.cls**, and **.zen**) and pass them to the Web Gateway module for processing.
>
> Apache 2.4.x: Use modules **CSPa24.so** and **CSPa24Sys.so**.

and

> 1. Apache 2.4.x: Add the section below to the end of **httpd.conf**.
>
>    ```
>    LoadModule csp_module_sa /opt/webgateway/bin/CSPa24.so
>    CSPModulePath /opt/webgateway/bin/      
>    <Location "/csp/bin/Systems/">
>    SetHandler cspsys-handler-sa
>    </Location>
>    <Location "/csp/bin/RunTime/">
>    SetHandler csp-handler-sa
>    </Location>
>    CSPFileTypes csp cls zen cxw 
>    Alias /csp/ /opt/webgateway/csp/
>    <Directory "/opt/webgateway/csp">
>             AllowOverride None
>             Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
>             Require all granted
>             <FilesMatch "\.(log|ini|pid|exe)$">
>             Require all denied 
>             </FilesMatch>
>    </Directory>
>    ```
> 2. Restart Apache after making changes to httpd.conf.